# How to get Bloch sphere Cartesian coordinates from density matrix

Tags: quantum-state, density-matrix, bloch-sphere

I am vexed by a particular derivation. Given a state $\psi$ and corresponding density matrix $\rho = |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$, or $\rho = \begin{bmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{bmatrix}$, I can compute the Bloch sphere coordinates as the following (in Python):

```
  a = rho[0, 0]
  b = rho[1, 0]
  x = 2.0 * b.real
  y = 2.0 * b.imag
  z = 2.0 * a - 1.0
```

This code works, but - how? I fail to properly derive it. Any hints or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: First, decompose the density matrix $\rho$ into the form $\rho = \dfrac{I + \vec{r} \cdot \vec{\sigma} }{2}  $ where $I$ is the 2 by 2 idenity matrix and $\vec{\sigma} = \langle X, Y, Z \rangle$ where $X,Y,Z$ are Pauli matrices. The vector $\vec{r}$ is the coordinate you are looking for.

Comment: see also https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4121/55. In the density matrix formalism, you just need to change $\langle\psi|\sigma_i|\psi\rangle$ into $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho \sigma_i)$ for $i=x,y,z$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point $(x, y, z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ corresponds to the state

$$
\rho = \frac{I + xX + yY + zZ}2 = \frac12\begin{bmatrix}
1+z & x-iy \\
x+iy & 1-z
\end{bmatrix},
$$

see also [definition in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere#Definition). Therefore, if $\rho = \begin{bmatrix}a & c \\ b & d\end{bmatrix}$, then

$$
2a = 1 + z \\
2b = x + i y
$$

and so

$$
x = 2\,\mathrm{Re}(b) \\
y = 2\,\mathrm{Im}(b) \\
z = 2a - 1.
$$