# Which angle convention is used in general equation of quantum state?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, bloch-sphere

In [this post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9474/20084), I am unsure which angles are denoted in general equation of quantum state.
I realize that $\theta$ is `azimuthal angle`, while $\phi$ is the `polar angle`. Some textbooks treat it reverse way.

- Which one is right?
- What is the domain of each angle?

[image]

Comment: see https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21830/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4118/55, and links therein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to visualise it: $|0\rangle$ is at the north pole of the sphere, and $|1\rangle$ is at the south pole. You get between them by varying the angle $\theta$ from 0 to $\pi$.

$\phi$ then defines an angle around the equator. Since it can be anywhere around the equator, it goes from 0 to $2\pi$. If you've got your visualisation correct, you should be able to confirm that there's no double-counting of positions on the surface of the sphere.