# why θ/2 in the Bloch sphere?

Tags: bloch-sphere

[Describing the Restricted Qubit State](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-states/representing-qubit-states.html#3.1-Describing-the-Restricted-Qubit-State-) is the best introduction I've seen on the Bloch sphere, but one thing still bugs me...
**Question:** Why use $θ/2$ instead of $θ$ or $zθ$ for that matter (i.e. ANY non-zero real factor of $θ$ will do)?  Once we choose $\phi=0$ (so $e^(i\phi)=1$, making everything real), EVERY choice of $x$ for $\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)$ will normalize the probabilities (i.e. produce a $1$).  There must be something else driving the choice of $θ/2$; *what is it?*

Comment: does [*Why are half angles used in the Bloch sphere representation of qubits?*](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4118/55) answer your question?

Comment: Still intuitively confusing, but I see how the 1/2 sneaks inside the trig functions.