# Why divide $\theta$ by 2 when doing the Bell's Inequality Experiment?

Tags: entanglement, measurement, bell-basis, bell-experiment, correlations

I understood the CHSH game correlations by watching [Prof. Vazirani's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUQYSy6C1aA). I also understood that the correlation between two measures taken from different basis are related by the cosine of the angle between the basis vectors (usually called $\theta$).

Now, when I watch other videos about the CHSH game ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f72whGQ31Wg)) when it comes to the moment of calculating the correlations between measurements, it is used $\frac{\theta}{2}$.

Why is that?

Comment: can you include in the post the way you are saying those sources use and define $\theta$ and $\theta/2$? These differences always just boil down to  different conventions and definitions used by different authors. In this case, the difference is likely of the same nature as the one discussed in https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4118/55